# Identify rows corresponding to values in df$columnA that occur twice, then assign a value in df$columnB

Tags: r, bioinformatics, tidyr, dplyr

I have a dataframe `pedigree` that looks like this:

```
FamilyID SampleID           MotherID            FatherID            Sex        
F1961    F1961-1_8005116592 F1961-3_8005116421  F1961-2_8005116603  1
F1961    F1961-2_8005116603 0                   0                   2   
F1961    F1961-3_8005116421 0                   0                   1   
0450     F350_8005441283    0                   0                   1   
0006     F355_8005441353    0                   0                   1   
0189     F359_8005441284    0                   0                   1   
0189     F359_8005441285    0                   0                   2
.
.
.
```

Some `FamilyIDs` (such as `0189`) show up twice, and those correspond to sibling pairs, whose parents' info was not recorded.

I need to add a "dummy fatherID / motherID" that is shared between those sibling pairs, for downstream analysis.

I'd like to identify specifically those samples whose `FamilyID` shows up two times, and assign them a shared `motherID` / `fatherID` value, so that example above would look like this:

**Desired Output:**

```
FamilyID SampleID           MotherID            FatherID            Sex        
F1961    F1961-1_8005116592 F1961-3_8005116421  F1961-2_8005116603  1
F1961    F1961-2_8005116603 0                   0                   2   
F1961    F1961-3_8005116421 0                   0                   1   
0450     F350_8005441283    0                   0                   1   
0006     F355_8005441353    0                   0                   1   
0189     F359_8005441284    0189_mother         0189_father         1   
0189     F359_8005441285    0189_mother         0189_father         2   
.
.
.
```

So far I've tried starting off with `mutate` to add a column indicating how many times each `FamilyID` is observed, but that's not working:

```
pedigree %>% 
  mutate(FamilySize = count(Family_ID))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "character".
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The `Family_ID = F1961` appears 3 times. Do you expect to update `MotherID` and `FatherID` even for those rows? If not, whats criteria to ignore it?

Comment: No, I'd like to update only the rows whose FamilyID appears twice. The ones whose Family ID appears 3x are trios, so it's OK that we don't know the mom's MotherID or the father's FatherID. The real issue are those sibling pairs that really have the same mom and dad but that info is not recorded in the data.

Comment: I guess you need to add back those new dummy parents as new rows, too, right?

Comment: @zx8754 Not in this case, as we don't actually have data on those individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the family size, we want to group them by `FamilyID`, and then count the rows in each group with `n()`. We can then use `mutate` with `if_else` to replace the value of `MotherID` or `FatherID` if needed. We can keep the table grouped by `FamilyID` here, actually, because all the variables that we're using in our mutate statement (`FamilySize`, `FatherID` and `MotherID`) are the same across the group. If they weren't (for example if we wanted to do something different based on `Sex`) then we would want to switch to `rowwise` so that mutate would apply the `if_else` functions on each row individually one by one, instead of a single vectorized calculation.

```
pedigree %>%
    group_by(FamilyID) %>%
    mutate(FamilySize = n()) %>%
    mutate(MotherID = if_else(FamilySize == 2 & MotherID == 0,
                              paste0(FamilyID, '_mother'),
                              MotherID),
           FatherID = if_else(FamilySize == 2 & FatherID == 0,
                              paste0(FamilyID, '_father'),
                              FatherID))

# A tibble: 7 x 6
  FamilyID SampleID           MotherID           FatherID             Sex FamilySize
  <chr>    <chr>              <chr>              <chr>              <int>      <int>
1 F1961    F1961-1_8005116592 F1961-3_8005116421 F1961-2_8005116603     1          3
2 F1961    F1961-2_8005116603 0                  0                      2          3
3 F1961    F1961-3_8005116421 0                  0                      1          3
4 0450     F350_8005441283    0                  0                      1          1
5 0006     F355_8005441353    0                  0                      1          1
6 0189     F359_8005441284    0189_mother        0189_father            1          2
7 0189     F359_8005441285    0189_mother        0189_father            2          2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` to group on `FamiliID` and update columns(MotherID/FatherID) for condition `n()==2`.

**Option#1**: Get the result in OP's expected format

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(FamilyID) %>%
  mutate(MotherID = ifelse(n() == 2, paste(FamilyID, "mother", sep= "_"), MotherID)) %>%
  mutate(FatherID = ifelse(n() == 2, paste(FamilyID, "father", sep= "_"), FatherID)) 

# FamilyID SampleID           MotherID           FatherID             Sex
# <chr>    <chr>              <chr>              <chr>              <int>
# 1 F1961    F1961-1_8005116592 F1961-3_8005116421 F1961-2_8005116603     1
# 2 F1961    F1961-2_8005116603 F1961-3_8005116421 F1961-2_8005116603     2
# 3 F1961    F1961-3_8005116421 F1961-3_8005116421 F1961-2_8005116603     1
# 4 0450     F350_8005441283    0                  0                      1
# 5 0006     F355_8005441353    0                  0                      1
# 6 0189     F359_8005441284    0189_mother        0189_father            1
# 7 0189     F359_8005441285    0189_mother        0189_father            2
```

**Option#2:** If OP is happy to have dummy IDs in form of `FamilyID_dummy` than a more elegant solution can be achieved using `mutate_at` as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(FamilyID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c("MotherID","FatherID")), 
              funs(ifelse(n() == 2, paste(FamilyID, "dummy", sep= "_"), .)))

# # A tibble: 7 x 5
# # Groups: FamilyID [4]
# FamilyID SampleID           MotherID           FatherID             Sex
# <chr>    <chr>              <chr>              <chr>              <int>
# 1 F1961    F1961-1_8005116592 F1961-3_8005116421 F1961-2_8005116603     1
# 2 F1961    F1961-2_8005116603 F1961-3_8005116421 F1961-2_8005116603     2
# 3 F1961    F1961-3_8005116421 F1961-3_8005116421 F1961-2_8005116603     1
# 4 0450     F350_8005441283    0                  0                      1
# 5 0006     F355_8005441353    0                  0                      1
# 6 0189     F359_8005441284    0189_dummy         0189_dummy             1
# 7 0189     F359_8005441285    0189_dummy         0189_dummy             2
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"FamilyID SampleID           MotherID            FatherID            Sex        
F1961    F1961-1_8005116592 F1961-3_8005116421  F1961-2_8005116603  1
F1961    F1961-2_8005116603 0                   0                   2   
F1961    F1961-3_8005116421 0                   0                   1   
0450     F350_8005441283    0                   0                   1   
0006     F355_8005441353    0                   0                   1   
0189     F359_8005441284    0                   0                   1   
0189     F359_8005441285    0                   0                   2",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! Technically, `0189_father` and `0189_mother` **are** different individuals, so making them both `0189_dummy` would confuse analysis down the road, but the `mutate_at + funs( )` solution is indeed elegant.

Comment: I'll make changes so that you can desired output in single function call. I'll be back to comp after a while.